# Drupal: Text Field, remove formatting tags

Tags: drupal, text, formatting, field

I have a Text Field added to a Content Type and I want to add a PayPal button in this field.

When I display the page, it shows the HTML in its entirety... rather than just the button.

Anyone know a work around or an override for this formatting?

Thx in advance :)

Comment: What kind of button is it that you want to add? A link, an image (presumably with a link), or a form item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a template file and rewrite the html and php.  For example the file will be called field--field_pay_pal.tpl.php (or whatever the machine name is) and and you will access the value using the $label value.  It may be in an associative array so to check the value use the dpm($label) to get the values.  Here is some more information below on the reference

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7

An example would be

```
<a href="example.com"><img src="<?php print $label[0][value]; ?>" /></a>
```